# Error in set_printoptions() in numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to use numpy to print an eye matrix with extra spaces , such as for input "3  3" , i get

```
[[ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.]]
```

My code for this program is as follows

```
 import numpy
    numpy.set_printoptions(sign =' ')
    N, M = input().split(' ')
    print(numpy.eye(int(N), int(M)))
```

But I am getting a type error as

> TypeError: set_printoptions() got an unexpected keyword argument
>   'sign'

I am using python 3.5.2 and PyCharm Community edition 2017.1.3 as an IDE. My code works perfectly fine on online editors for python 3. So is it a problem with my IDE/python installation or a problem in numpy?

Comment: You appear to be using an old version of numpy - the `sign=` option was added sometime between versions 1.9 and 1.13.

Comment: Thats right , upgraded numby to version 1.4 and it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the numpy version, as stated in the comment by jasonsharper. Upgraded from numpy version 1.12 to 1.14 and the code works fine now.